# Textbox gets back focus upon timepicker close

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-ui-dialog, datetimepicker, tab-ordering

I'm using [the timepicker plugin for jquery](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/).

Once users selected a date+time and click on the "Done" button, which basically just closes the dialog, I want the textbox where datetime is set to gain back focus (the current behavior of the plugin is to blur out focus).

This is because on this page I have a set of textboxes and their tab orders are set sequentially. I need the datetime textbox to gain back focus to continue the tab order. otherwise the tab order will restart from the first text input which is inconvenient for the user.

Comment: Please format your posts; also, greetings and thanks are redundant. Finally, don't write tags in titles - the fact that you've done it differently each time is a perfect example of why we have an indexable and consistent tags system _instead_.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the helpful suggestions, especially the no tag in title one which i agree 100%, but why is that greetings and thanks are redundant?

Comment: This isn't a forum or a chatroom or a set of emails or letters, but a compilation of _questions_ and _answers_. Chatter is redundant (that's what comments are for! sort of). http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts

Comment: OK that makes sense. I think the succinct nature of Q&A outweighs the benefit of personal touch. thanks again. my posts do look better after your edits!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Description

Assuming i understand your question, you can set the focus to your textbox in the `onClose` event. Please provide more information if this is not the right answer. `html` or better a `jsFiddle` would be great.

#### Sample

```
$('#MyDatepicker').datetimepicker({
    onClose: function(dateText, inst) {
       $('#MyDatepicker').focus();
    }
});
```

#### More Information

- [jQuery.focus()](http://api.jquery.com/focus/)

### Update

If you have several datePickers you can do this.

1. Gave them all the same css class.
2. Do this

   ```
       $('.MyDatePickerClass').datetimepicker({
           onClose: function(dateText, inst) {
              $('.MyDatePickerClass').focus();
           }
       });
   ```

Comment: You are awesome! this works. but just one more question pls - upon close now it does give focus back to my textbox, but that in turn opens the datepicker again. i was researching how to prevent that. if you know off the top of your head, would you point me to the right direction? thanks a lot!

Comment: Thx @Lagoona a really good question. With the regular jQuery datepicker i know how to prevent that. But, at the moment, i am thinking how you can do this using the plugin you are using. A way you can do this, but not really elegant, is to close the picker after `$('.MyDatePickerClass').focus();`. Let us talk about it, iam sure we find an answer.

Comment: Thanks again @dknaack! i tried to close the picker after focus() but it caused infinite loop. i've decided to put the new issue into a separate question so it can stand out more.

Comment: link to the new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8763134/jquery-prevent-timepicker-addon-from-opening-calendar